# c++ profiling of the g++ based application with libraries

Tags: c++

I'm trying to find performance problems inside melt framework and especially with affine transformations.

I've tried 3 profilers: gprof, Zoom and GooglePerfomanceTools.

I've compiled all code with disabled optimizations and explicitly removed any inline functions changing it by ordinary functions.

But all of this profilers getting me unresolved function names in a Call Graph. In the true is that the most of these functions are the most time consuming.

So the question is what is the correct procedure to profile g++ based application with libraries

Thanks,

Comment: Have you enabled debugging flags (`-g3` for g++)?

Answer (score 1):

you need to compile your program with debugging info enabled (which I assume you did, but mentioning it nonetheless), install debug enabled versions of your dependency libraries, and link your program against them.

in debian based linux environments, they are usually named like the original library, with a -dbg suffix. for example, libxml2-dbg.

hope this helps.

Comment: yes sure i did it, i've compiled required libraries from sources with enable debugging option